# Definition of resultCodes when using chrome.socket module

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

The `chrome.socket.read` callback will return a `ReadInfo` object which includes a `resultCode` property. This either contains the number of bytes read or a negative integer indicating an error.

I have been looking for some time for a definition of the negative resultCodes as I am occasionaly getting a `-15` which seems to occur when one end-point is closed.

Tried looking at the [reference docs](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html) and at the [source code](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/socket.idl?view=markup) itself but I couldn't figure out where the resultCodes are defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error codes seem to be those for net::ERROR_XXXX, which can be found at 
http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/net/base/net_error_list.h

However, it may not be a good idea to depend on these error codes since it is undocumented and may change at any time.